# Why can't topic aliases be stored in a persistent session in MQTT v5

Tags: mqtt

From what I understand Topic Aliases are not stored in the session state. [Section [4.1](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901230) MQTT 5 spec]

For us this means that each time the device connects, a mapping of Topic name to Alias using the Publish packet has to be made, increasing the comms time and keeping the device awake for longer.

I would prefer it if I only mapped the Topic names to topic Aliases when I start a new session. Resulting in sending less data and the device can quickly go back to sleep.

The broker we are using is EMQX, I have created a support ticket.

I am aware storing the Aliases increases the storage requirements for the session state.

Can anybody else confirm this and how have they overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section [3.3.2.3.4](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Topic_Alias) of the MQTTv5 spec

> Topic Alias mappings exist only within a Network Connection and last only for the lifetime of that Network Connection. A receiver MUST NOT carry forward any Topic Alias mappings from one Network Connection to another [MQTT-3.3.2-7].

It is explicit in the spec that they must not be part of the Stored Session data.

Comment: I did see that, in the spec, but forgot to mention it. It is disappointing that it is not part of the spec. Thanks for replying.

Comment: The reason is because you can't guarantee that the client has been able to maintain state over the restart, so it wouldn't know what aliases map to which topics. (Also aliases tend to be based on the order of the messages sent so can change with each session)

Comment: I didn't think of that. Seems like it's more complicated than I thought. Thanks again.